# Prepare Segue not working on SplitViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, segue

Using Swift 3 I have developed project and it's hierarchy is as below:

> Tabbar -> SplitViewController -> NavigationController -> TableView

**1.** When I am not using a SplitViewController and connecting the Tabbar directly to the NavigationController, the prepare method is called perfectly.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
                case "segueCarDetails":
                    let nextScene = segue.destination as! CarDetailsViewController
    //etc etc etc
```

2. However when connecting the tabbar to the SplitViewController, the segue is not being called.

What can be wrong ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It used to be that the split view controller needed to be the root view controller, not sure if that's still the case

Comment: after SplitViewController added, your `segue.destination` should be `SplitViewController`

Comment: Some reformation of statement and formatting changes

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today - I solved the issue by programmatically performing the segue:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueCarDetails", sender: self)
}
```

Hope that solves your problem!